# Patterns not recognized after executing EXEC action

Tags: uima, ruta

I have a strange problem with Apache UIMA Ruta (2.6.1) that I don't understand. I made the following script to demonstrate the situation. I recognize some patterns in the input text and create patterns from it.

After execution of the EXEC action patterns based on combination of annotations are not recognized:

For the following script I tried to use input text "aaa bbb". PATTERN_A is recognized (created) but PATTERN_B not.

Single annotations are still recognized (AAA_2 is created).

I serialized to a XCAS (cas) object before and after the EXEC command, and both files are equal.

Note: the TableLookupAnalysisEngine use an empty ruta script in this example. If I add a custom annotation in the script it also work.

```
ENGINE TableLookupAnalysisEngine;

DECLARE AAA;
DECLARE AAA_1;
DECLARE AAA_2;
DECLARE BBB;
DECLARE PATTERN_A;
DECLARE PATTERN_B;

"aaa"{-> MARK(AAA)};
"bbb"{-> MARK(BBB)};

AAA{-> AAA_1};
(AAA BBB){-> PATTERN_A};

Document{-> CONFIGURE(TableLookupAnalysisEngine, "dictRemoveWS" = true),
                EXEC(TableLookupAnalysisEngine, {AAA, BBB})};

AAA{-> AAA_2};

// Not recognized -> internal index numbers changed?
(AAA BBB){-> PATTERN_B};
```

Answer (score 1):

We tried the same test in Eclipse Workbench and get the expected result. The pattern matching after the EXEC command still work.

Because the XML descriptor files used in our project and Eclipse Workbench where equal we looked into the engine execution code:

We changed the following statement to solve the problem.

From:

```
JCas jCas = CasCreationUtils.createCas(rutaEngine.getAnalysisEngineMetaData()).getJCas();
```

To:

```
JCas jCas = rutaEngine.newJCas();
```

Comment: Ah ok, I have to take a closer look at it. Are it the TypePriorities, Indexes? I would have thought that they are included in the metadata.

Comment: We generate the engine file(s) and type descriptors based on the ruta files (we use the RutaDescriptorFactory for that, just like the Eclipse plugin do). The generated MainEngine.xml contains the 3 default type priorities (RutaFrame, Annotation, RutaBasic) and all the type descriptors included. We create the ruta engine based on that MainEngine.xml. Before processing a document we create the cas on that engine.

Comment: I compared the both cas objects and see that the used classloader (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader in first one, and org.apache.uima.internal.util.UIMAClassLoader in the second one) is different. Also some other items are different, for example: In the second one (working one) the org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSGenerator-array have entries and it's empty in the first one. I have a lack of knowledge to know the result of that differences.
Our problem is solved with using ```rutaEngine.newJCas();``` and that's also cleaner code. We are happy with it now.

Comment: Without looking in the code, I would guess that the difference should be cuased by a different state of the JCas initialization. Just in case you want to create a CAS withtout an analysis engine description, you could use the createCas with different arguments or use the uimaFIT Factorie which provides classpath scanning for the priorities.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the relevant type for internal Ruta reindexing by adding them in a TypeList as a second argument. There is an example in the documentation:

```
ENGINE NamedEntities;
Document{->EXEC(NamedEntities, {Person, Location})};
```

In your example, you probably need to add `{AAA, BBB}`.

DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta:

Comment: I also played with that options (without passing the view into the action, and adding annotations to the "reindex list"). Same result